# Locked out after installing a bash without executable bit

Tags: permissions, bash, shell, login

After `scp`-ing a shellshock-patched `bash` binary to an openSUSE 12.2 Linux VM and replacing the login shell with it, no user can log in via `ssh` or the console. As it turned out, the executable bit got lost during transfer, despite using the `-p` switch.

I tried to repair this by mounting the filesystem on the Linux Xen host and doing `chmod +x /mnt/usr/local/bin/bash`, but the situation did not improve. Will rebooting the guest VM help?

This is what I see on console:

```
xxx login: root
Password:
Last login: xxx
Have a lot of fun...
 -- root: no shell: permission denied
```

This appears in `/mnt/var/log/messages` …

on ssh login:

```
sshd: User root not allowed because shell /bin/bash is not executable
sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]
sshd: Postponed keyboard-interactive for invalid user root from x.x.x.x port xxxxx ssh2 [preauth]
```

on console login:

```
systemd-logind: New session x of user root.
login: ROOT LOGIN ON xvc0
console-kit-daemon: WARNING: Unable to spawn /etc/ConsoleKit/run-session.d/dbus_at_console.ck: Failed to execute child process "/etc/ConsoleKit/run-session.d/dbus_at_console.ck" (Permission denied)
systemd-logind: Removed session x.
```

And this is how I caused the problem:

```
# my /bin/bash has been a symlink to /usr/local/bin/bash since the first shellshock patch
scp -p buildhost:/tmp/bash /tmp/bash
# then I forgot to do chmod +x /tmp/bash
# then I forgot to do chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh, logout and login
mv /tmp/bash /usr/local/bin/bash && \
mv /bin/bash /var/tmp/bash-unpatched && \
chmod -x /var/tmp/bash-unpatched && \
ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

Replacing the `/bin/bash` symlink by a real binary did not help either.

Comment: What if you mount the filesystem in Xen again, but edit /etc/passwd  and change your shell to /bin/dash (or another installed shell)?  Then you can login and fix the bash issue.  (if this works I'll make it an answer)

Comment: I tried that several times before. No change.

Comment: Is this an extX filesystem? You can't mount those more than once. You'll need to shut down the guest, then make the change.

Comment: Yes it is. Luckily, I found a user who was still logged into the guest VM. In his terminal, I found out that the guest filesystem modifications I had made from the Xen host had not taken effect. So I did `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bash` from that terminal again, and this time it worked. Thanks for the great advice! I should have mentioned that I am a Xen newbie, but you probably realized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to reboot.  File permission changes done from the hypervisor to a file system in use by a guest won't be detected by the guest.

In the future when doing this type of 'update' have a separate shell session open to the server you're updating, just in case things go south.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some access to the server.  There are various approaches you can try.

You should have a working ssh client, try using ssh to either fix the permissions, or login with a different shell.

```
ssh root@host chmod +x /bin/bash
ssh root@host /bin/dash
```

If you can connect to a non-root user, try `sudo`.

```
sudo chmod +x /bin/dash
sudo /bin/bash
```

Or just use `su` from the non-root user

```
su -c 'chmod +x /bin/bash'
su -c '/bin/dash'
```

You should be able to find the available shells in `/etc/shells`.